# Where can I buy bulk wild meat in Montreal?

Tags: meat, shopping

I've been to marché atwater and they said that usually they have in stock in the winter. But one of the stores had Bison but it wasn't totally wild but still was walking in the forest. 
I want to increase my wild meat intake but is seems so hard to find. Where can I buy it?

Comment: http://firstpeoplesofcanada.com/images/firstnations/teachers_guide/inuit/hunt_bowarrow.jpg ?

Comment: Only applies to Montreal, are we going to do this for every small city in the world?

Answer (score 4):

From what I have gathered searching for an answer to this question, caribou, seal, and hare are the only actual wild game meats that can be purchased in Canada. Due to low demand, hare and seal may be very difficult to find, even in-season. All other "game meat" including "wild" boar, venison, bison, and rabbit is farm-raised and butchered. There is no farmed moose in North America. A recent  [web article](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/montreal/wild-game-meat-to-be-served-by-quebec-restaurants-1.2549277) from the CBC, makes it seem like there may soon be a chance to find some trapped wild game on a limited number of Montreal menus, but not necessarily in stores anytime soon.

In the US we have similar restrictions that may vary slightly state-to-state. The venison, bison, ostrich, turkey, pheasant, and quail available for purchase is all farm-raised and often imported from other countries. Wild boar from [Texas](http://wildboarmeats.com/the-meat/), though, may be wild/feral and is trapped by permitted individuals and butchered at USDA approved facilities. USDA regulations require ante- and post-mortem inspection, meaning that the animals must be delivered to the slaughterhouse alive. These regulations limit the number of domestic wild boar available, even though we have a huge wild hog problem throughout the South, California, and Hawaii.

It seems that the only way to get actual game meat is to be a hunter or know a hunter who is willing to share the fruits of their labor.  In my experience, many hunters don't know what to do with large portions of the meat, and just grind almost everything but the loin and tenderloin into burger. It might be easier to get some of those tougher cuts from the front and hind limbs, especially if you offer to share some stew, a slow roasted shoulder, or some braised neck medallions.

Sources:

- http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/410204
- http://forums.egullet.org/topic/37573-wild-game-restaurant-in-montreal/
- http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g155032-i51-k7231237-o20-Serving_wild_game-Montreal_Quebec.html

Place to try contacting:

- Boucherie De Paris Enr, 5216 Avenue Gatineau, Montréal (514) 731-6615
- Volailles Et Gibiers Fernando, 106 Roy E, Montréal (514) 843-6652
- Also [Kivalliq Arctic Foods](http://ndcorp.nu.ca/subsidiaries/kivaliq/) in Nunavut (867) 645-3137, see if they can cold-ship it to you

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't *where*, the issue is *when*.

If you're looking for wild game, you're only going to find it (or find it at reasonable prices) during the proper [hunting season for your area](http://montreal.angloinfo.com/information/lifestyle/hunting/) ... assuming you're even in an area that allows wild game meat to be sold.

Hunting laws vary by location, but most hunters won't kill animals that they can't consume, so you might be able to find someone who has capacity on their license, and would be willing to sell (or give, if they're not allowed to sell it) a whole or half animal, assuming they can bag it.

Your other option off-season is what's known as 'roadkill salvage' (collecting the carcasses of wild animals that have been hit by vehicles), but many areas have laws about that, too.  (outlawing it, allowing it if you have a license but you're not allowed to sell the meat, etc.)

... or you just get farm-raised meat.

Comment: +1, the folks at Marché Atwater were presumably just indirectly telling the OP roughly when the season was.